# How to find a class within a div id using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

When the user click the like button, I am trying to capture the number in the class 'badge'.  Here's what I have in my JS so far where I find the div id containing the elements but I'm having trouble going down and finding .badge within this div:

```
//Like annotation JS
  $('.liking').click(function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  div = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
  console.log(div);

})
//End of liking annotation JS


<div id = 'div1'>
<% @annotations.each do |annotation| %>
    <p><strong>Name</strong>
    <p class = 'lead' style = 'font-size: 14px; line-height: 23px;'>
        <%= annotation.annotation %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <small>
            <span class = 'badge' style = 'font-size: 12px;'>0</span> &nbsp;
            <a href = "#" class = 'liking'>
                Like
            </a>
        </small>
    </p>
    <hr class="featurette-divider" style = 'margin:15px;'>
<% end %> <!-- End of verse annotations -->
</div>
```

Comment: If the HTML is always going to be in this structure, `.badge` is just the previous sibling of the `<a class="liking">` - so jQuery's [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) function could be a simpler solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need the ID, you can use the `find` method, you can also use `siblings` method.

```
$('.liking').click(function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var $badge = $(this).closest('div').find('.badge');      
  // var $badge = $(this).siblings('.badge');
  console.log($badge.text());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
badge = $(this).closest('div').find('.badge');
```

But in your HTML, `badge` is always right before `liking`, so you can do:

```
badge = $(this).siblings('.badge');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var text = $(this).siblings('span.badge').text();
var number = parseInt(text, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried this?

```
$('.liking').click(function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  div = $(this).closest('div').find('.badge');
  console.log(div);

})
```

here is working link http://jsfiddle.net/ASN7c/

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code

```
$('.liking').click(function (e){
e.preventDefault()
var div1 =  $(this).closest('div').find('.badge'); 
alert(div1.text());

})
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/JU7Sj/)

Answer (score 0):

Will `.badge` always be the parent element of the `.liking` link?

If so, you can simply do:

```
 $('.liking').click(function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var $badge = $(this).prev();
  console.log($badge.text());
})
```

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/2c9xz/

Comment: I've made this mistake before. `prev()` doesn't work because there's a text node in between them.